# How to execute kill `ps -ef | grep 1.sh` command as SUDO SU from batch file through Putty terminal to kill ALL process, with given name not only 1st?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, putty, grep

I try use this command:

```
start "" putty.exe -ssh -load NameOfSessionInPutty -m "C:\Program Files\PuTTY\MYCOMMAND.txt" -t
```

`MYCOMMAND.txt` contains:

```
sudo su - -c "kill `ps -ef | grep 1.sh`"
```

But the above command kills only 1 line (first that it finds),
and I need to find and kill ALL processes with this name `1.sh`.

When I do this manually:

```
kill `ps -ef | grep 1.sh`
```

it works perfectly, killing all processes with this name.

But `` sudo su - -c "kill `ps -ef | grep 1.sh`" `` kills only the first one found and closes the session.

Help, please, whoever understands what I need to change in the code.

Comment: thanks, for quick response, if you kind, help me what command need use?) To have same result from 1line code to use through batch file, as using by hands command "kill 'ps -ef | grep 1.sh'" from terminal

Comment: Have you tried putting the script on the "other side" and calling THAT from the batch file?

Comment: When you do `kill …`, the inside of the backticks is evaluated before `kill`. When you do `sudo …`, the inside of the backticks is evaluated before `sudo` (and then [maybe `ps` only sees some PIDs](https://superuser.com/a/704035/432690)). I don't know the mechanics of PuTTY, but if the command is going to be evaluated in Linux then try single-quotes instead of double-quotes. There may be other issues and the resulting command may not be optimal, but at least you will delay the evaluation of the backticks.

Comment: Why `sudo su - -c "kill ` ` `ps -ef | grep 1.sh` ` `"` and not just `sudo "kill ` ` `ps -ef | grep 1.sh` ` `"` ? Or probably `sudo 'kill ` ` `ps -ef | grep 1.sh` ` `'` would be even better?

Comment: Thanks for response, @Peregrino69 no problem, @Kamil Maciorowki I try yours advice, when I put single quote in my version sudo su - -c 'kill `ps -ef | grep 1.sh`' I recieve same result as with double quotes:

-bash: line 0: kill: root: arguments must be process or job IDs
Terminated

...So process terminated, after 1st line,
when I try sudo 'kill `ps -ef | grep 1.sh`', I recieve answer:


sudo: kill `ps -ef | grep 1.sh`: command not found    ... Problem not solved with that... Single quoute makes no difference, other command not work

Comment: @Señor CMasMas yes, thanks for advice, it worked for me! I put script on CentOs: `#!/bin/bash sudo su - -c 'kill `ps -ef | grep go2.sh`'` and call it from batch through putty and it remove all process in 1 time, looks like sudo su - -c "...." has some restrictions when is called from "this side" to kill only 1 process and finish. 
But still interesting is there any solution to make it working from "this side"?

Comment: Nope ;)  Or I would have posted an answer and not a work-around. :)  Good luck figuring it out.

Comment: @Señor CMasMas
then, thanks again for good advice) save me many time. I will stop on it

Comment: [`pkill`](http://manpages.org/pkill) is much easier to get right

Comment: dave_thompson_085 thanks man a lot! I just use `pkill -f 1.sh` and it worked for me much better! (Instead of variant above, which I test again from "that side" and not work again, dont know yesterday not test porperly) ..... somehow `sudo su - -c 'pkill -f 1.sh' ` works from "this side" directly from batch file through putty without problem, killing all process with given name! Thanks again, to best answer – @dave_thompson_085   And thanks to all who try help) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you combine `sudo`with `su`. Seems to me like an overkill to get root-rights. Instead you could use ...

```
sudo kill ...
```

or

```
su kill ... -
```

To kill all processes named *1.sh* you can combine `pgrep` (to find all the PIDs) with `kill` (to send a **SIGTERM** to all those PIDs).

```
pgrep "1.sh" | xargs kill
```

You could also use `pkill` which is the same as explained before but combined all into one command.

```
pkill "1.sh"
```

An alternative is `killall` to send **SIGTERM** to all processes with that name.

```
killall "1.sh"
```

Answer (score 0):

Kill command needs only PIDs(integers), I'm not sure how can you get that with just `ps -ef | grep 1.sh`

I'm assuming that you've to kill all the process instances of **1.sh** script.

If `pidof` binary is available in your machine, you can just use `pidof 1.sh | xargs sudo kill`, put this command inside your `MYCOMMAND.txt` file

Comment: when I put that command it give me answer: `pidof 1.sh | xargs sudo kill`  Usage: kill [options] <pid|name> [...] Options: ......... For more details see kill(1). ...... Maybe I will try this `ps -ef | grep 1.sh | xargs sudo kill`   .....when I try last it give answer: .....
kill: cannot find process "root"
Terminated
 ......, so only working answer for me now (from @Señor CMasMas), is to start from "that side" from script .sh

Answer (score 0):

Best answer: use other command `sudo su - -c 'pkill -f 1.sh'` in txt file, instead of `sudo su - -c "kill` ps -ef | grep 1.sh`"` .

Works properly.

Finding and killing all process with given name "1.sh", as example.

Thanks, @dave_thompson_085 for giving advice, to try pkill (that easier to get right for it)